# Make the button available if all fields are filled (Android)

Tags: java, android

There are 4 EditText, once all filled, you need to make the button available

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: And if we don't want? More seriously, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether text is entered in edittext like this and set a boolean flag to true if it text is entered

```
if (!mEditText.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    textflag=true
}
```

and if text is not entered reset the boolean flag to false and break from the loop and you can check it like this..

```
if (mEditText.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
    textflag=false
}
```

Use `addTextChangedListener` like this

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
         enableSubmitIfReady();
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  }
});
```

Comment: Glad that you understood :) @user3593350

Answer (score 1):

Add TextWatchers to each EditText to know when the content changes.

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.toString().trim().length() >0)
                     //it is not empty
        });
```

Check the content of each EditText by `mEditText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0`

If all of them return true, then `mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: Where better to do that as soon as I typed in the last empty EditText symbol button becomes available?

Comment: Check my answer for that @swayam

Comment: @Lal : Yup. I was aware of TextWatcher. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Check my answer for that @user3593350